# I am trying to report what is an issue with RPMfusion.org repository, regarding the build of VLC therein. What discusion groups and tags should I use?

Tags: vlc

I am trying to report what I believe is an issue with RPMfusion.org repository, regarding the build of VLC therein.

Since the repository has hundreds of packages thereon, there seems to be nobody who wants to claim ownership of items posted there.

---

Rémi Denis-Courmont @Courmisch · 4 minutes ago    Maintainer

### Sorry but this is not a suitable venue to report issues with RPMfusion.org, which people here have zero control over.

After several attempts at emailing individuals at RPMfusion.org, I tried posting the issue as an issue in the code repository at videolan.org and got my finger smacked again.

My issue is that hundreds of downloads from the repository are getting a version of VLC that cannot properly play DVD menus. This only happens for those using the repository, so that rules out Windows and other non-RPM repositories.

I have about three pages of screenshots and instructions to quickly reproduce the problem. I think it *may* be a build issue, but cannot prove that to be the case.

Videolan.org doesn't want it: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/27030#note_328247

RPMfusion.org by emails tell me "it is a package maintainer issue", and they don't want it.  [[private emails]]

Anyone know anyone who might know who maintains VLC on RPMfusion.org??? Or where I might best post that question to reach a proper audience?

There is a VLC tag here, but not an "RPMfusion" one.

Thank you.

Comment: See https://rpmfusion.org/ReportingBugs

Comment: @Remi - Your link is to the originator of the private emails I mentioned above.

RPMfusion told me they don't update the packages in their repositories; rather that process is up to the individual creators of each package - VLC being one such example among many.

You loudly complained to me from VideoLan - It's a build issue! It's an installation issue!! But I say so what?; especially if the problem is so easy to **ALWAYS** reproduce, and do so by just by following the simple instructions that are found at the VideoLan wehsite? If not someone at VideoLan, then Who?